# Preserving PS1 while in SSH with GitBash?

Tags: bash, git, ssh, git-bash

I have a complicated prompt. Very. I use git-bash for windows.

SSH-ing in on gitbash sends me to the CMD prompt. I know to type `ssh -t user@host "bash -l"` to get a bash prompt. It works, however, I use a repository called `gitstatus` to speed up the parsing of the git commands, and sshing in using `bash -l` calls the PS1 set in `/c/cygwin/etc/bash.bashrc` (for Mintty), NOT `~/bash.bashrc` (for GitBash). This initially seems fine, as I can just copy paste the code from the GitBash *.bashrc to cygwin's. However, the gitstatus repository only works on bash terminals, aka not Cygwin/Mintty, so the prompt when I ssh in appears quite slower in git repos (Mintty doesn't allow gitstatus to be sourced and speed up parsing, once again) than if I was not SSH-ed in and using the GitBash-sourced prompt.

Are there any work arounds for this? I have seen many simnilar questions here but none have provided me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in my situation, just source the scripts (duh). If you can't execute `foo` in file `x` when it should do the same thing as `bar` in file `y`, just source `bar` from file `x`. It seems obvious but took me a moment.
ALSO: Make sure to run dos2unix.exe on admin command prompt to remove carriage returns every time you make a change.